# How to make a variable using keys from literal object, javascript

Tags: javascript, key

In an exercise, I have to make a variable called "fullAddress" that contains everything in a given literal object except for the first key.

I found a solution that sort of works, but I feel like there is a better way to do it. Also, I can't figure out how to efficiently put space between the values in the variable.

The exercise says the final result should look something like this:

39 Johnson Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11206

But mine looks like this:

39 Johnson AveBrooklynNY11206

---

Literal Object provided in exercise:

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
}
```

My solution:

```
let fullAddress = restaurant.address + restaurant.city + restaurant.state + restaurant.zipcode;
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Add a space with a string in between. `restaurant.address + " " + restaurant.city` or use string template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

Given an array of strings, you can use `values.join(', ')` to put commas between the values cleanly. Then you could do e.g. `[restaurant.address, restaurant.city, restaurant.state, restaurant.zipcode].join(', ')`.

If you wanted to do this more generically for any object, you could use `Object.values(restaurant).slice(1).join(', ')` to dynamically get all values after the first and comma delimit them.

In this case though, I think it makes the most sense to just explicitly append with commas since it's an address format (maybe you don't want a space after the zip code for example), so something like `restaurant.address + ', ' + restaurant.city + ...`

Comment: Thanks! That all makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding spaces (and commas), you can use a template string as done for `restaurant.address`.

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
};

let fullAddress = `${restaurant.address}, ${restaurant.city}, ${restaurant.state}, ${restaurant.zipcode}`;
console.log(fullAddress); // 39 Johnson Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11206
```

Next, notice we're actually joining all the address-parts with the same delimiter: `', '`. This means we can use `[].join()` instead.

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
};

let addressParts = [restaurant.address, restaurant.city, restaurant.state, restaurant.zipcode];
let fullAddress = addressParts.join(', ');
console.log(fullAddress); // 39 Johnson Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11206
```

Lastly, (if you want to get fancy), note that `restaurant.` is repeated. This can be avoided with `[].map()`.

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
};

let fullAddress = ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode']
    .map(key => restaurant[key])
    .join(', ');
console.log(fullAddress); // 39 Johnson Ave, Brooklyn, NY, 11206
```

Comment: Thanks for laying that all out! I forgot about template literals. I haven't learned about maps yet-- I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

You can take out all the values from the restaurant object, remove the first element and then use join to get the desired string

```js
const restaurant = {
   name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
   address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
   city: 'Brooklyn',
   state: 'NY',
   zipcode: '11206',
}

const fullAddress = Object.values(restaurant).slice(1).join(', ');
console.log(fullAddress);
```